# SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else'

Tags: javascript

I'm practising some code and got some error, Can anyone help me out.

Showing error like:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else'

Below is the code

```
var ageJohn = 25;
var heightJohn = 165;

var ageSmith = 60;
var heightSmith = 180;

var ageMalli = 24;
var heightMalli = 170;

var scoreJohn = heightJohn + 5 * ageJohn;
var scoreSmith = heightSmith + 5 * ageSmith;
var scoreMalli = heightMalli + 5 * ageMalli;


if (scoreJohn > scoreSmith && scoreJohn > scoreMalli); {
    console.log('John wins with ' + scoreJohn);
} else if (scoreSmith > scoreJohn && scoreSmith > scoreMalli); {
    console.log('Smith wins with! ' + scoreSmith);
} else(scoreMalli > scoreJohn && scoreMalli > scoreSmith); {
    console('Mary wins with ' + scoreMalli);
}
```

Comment: The error that you can see is just one of errors you have.
In your, if else statements you shouldn't have semicolons at the end just before the brackets.

Here is a whole article about why not:
[Your guide to semicolons][1]


  [1]: https://www.codecademy.com/blog/78

    else(scoreMalli > scoreJohn && scoreMalli > scoreSmith) {
    console('Mary wins with ' + scoreMalli);}

your `else` statement can't have anything in the brackets.
You should restructure it to `else if` if you want to do that check `(scoreMalli > scoreJohn && scoreMalli > scoreSmith)`

Answer (score 2):

You have one extra `;`. The error is here:

```
} else if (scoreSmith > scoreJohn && scoreSmith > scoreMalli); {
```

Change to

```
} else if (scoreSmith > scoreJohn && scoreSmith > scoreMalli) {
```

And two other line with if have similar issue

Answer (score 2):

remove ";" should be:

```
if (scoreJohn > scoreSmith && scoreJohn > scoreMalli) {
   console.log('John wins with ' + scoreJohn);
} else if (scoreSmith > scoreJohn && scoreSmith > scoreMalli) {
   console.log('Smith wins with! ' + scoreSmith);
} else(scoreMalli > scoreJohn && scoreMalli > scoreSmith) {
   console('Mary wins with ' + scoreMalli);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a ; after your if statement, removing that should work fine.

```
    if (scoreJohn > scoreSmith && scoreJohn > scoreMalli) {
        console.log('John wins with ' + scoreJohn);
    } else if (scoreSmith > scoreJohn && scoreSmith > scoreMalli) {
        console.log('Smith wins with! ' + scoreSmith);
    } else(scoreMalli > scoreJohn && scoreMalli > scoreSmith) {
        console('Mary wins with ' + scoreMalli);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ageJohn = 25;
var heightJohn = 165;

var ageSmith = 60;
var heightSmith = 180;

var ageMalli = 24;
var heightMalli = 170;

var scoreJohn = heightJohn + 5 * ageJohn;
var scoreSmith = heightSmith + 5 * ageSmith;
var scoreMalli = heightMalli + 5 * ageMalli;


if (scoreJohn > scoreSmith && scoreJohn > scoreMalli) {
    console.log('John wins with ' + scoreJohn)
} else if (scoreSmith > scoreJohn && scoreSmith > scoreMalli) {
    console.log('Smith wins with! ' + scoreSmith)
} else if(scoreMalli > scoreJohn && scoreMalli > scoreSmith) {
    console('Mary wins with ' + scoreMalli);
}
```

I removed the semicolons from the `if` statements and fixed the last `else if`

Answer (score 0):

You've got some syntax errors.

```
if (scoreJohn > scoreSmith && scoreJohn > scoreMalli) {
    console.log('John wins with ' + scoreJohn);
} else if (scoreSmith > scoreJohn && scoreSmith > scoreMalli) {
    console.log('Smith wins with! ' + scoreSmith);
} else if (scoreMalli > scoreJohn && scoreMalli > scoreSmith) {
    console('Mary wins with ' + scoreMalli);
}
```

Your else clause cant have a condition in it, you should extend that to another else if.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of `if` statement is like;

```
if (condition or Boolean value)
    statement;
else
    statement;
```

`statement` must be complex one written `{...}`.
You wrote `;` after `(condition)`, so `if` clause is ended with empty statement.
That's why, `else` raises syntax error. Thank you for reading.